# Hibernate retrieving an extra, NULL, row

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two tables **Config** and **Setting** where **Setting** are part (children) of a **Configuration**.

I'm using HibernateDaoSupport.find() to retrieve a Configuration and the resulting object contains 3 Settings, one of which is **null**. Not an object with empty values, but just **null**.

According to the logs Hibernate found only two rows:

```
DEBUG [org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager] - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad] - resolving associations for [com.xx.Setting#1]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad] - done materializing entity [com.xx.Setting#1]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad] - resolving associations for [com.xx.Setting#2]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad] - done materializing entity [com.xx.Setting#2]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext] - 1 collections were found in result set for role: com.xx.Configuration.settings
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext] - collection fully initialized: [com.xx.Configuration.settings#1]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext] - 1 collections initialized for role: com.xx.Configuration.settings
DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.Loader] - done loading collection
```

and then

```
DEBUG [org.hibernate.pretty.Printer] - com.xx.Setting{dataType=TEXT, name=xx, id=1, value=xx}
DEBUG [org.hibernate.pretty.Printer] - com.xx.Configuration{settings=[null, com.xx.Setting#1, com.xx.Setting#2], id=1, bu=xx}
DEBUG [org.hibernate.pretty.Printer] - com.xx.Setting{dataType=TEXT, name=xx, id=2, value=xx}
```

As you can see it found only 2 **Setting** but the collection contains 3.

EDIT: Following is the Hibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.xx.Configuration"
         table="sf_config"
         dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false"
         mutable="true" optimistic-lock="version"
         polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" lazy="false">
    <id access="field" name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <natural-id>
      <property name="bu" access="field"/>
    </natural-id>

    <list access="field" name="settings" table="sf_setting" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key>
        <column name="configId"/>
      </key>
      <list-index column="id"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.xx.Setting"/>
    </list>

    <property name="recordState" access="field"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.xx.Setting"
         table="sf_setting"
         dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false"
         mutable="true" optimistic-lock="version"
         polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false" lazy="false">
    <id access="field" name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="name" access="field"/>
    <property name="value" access="field"/>
    <property name="dataType" access="field"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What's the actual content of the DB? I'm wondering if this can be the result of an improperly setup join table without foreign key constraints that references a non-existing setting...

Comment: The DB contains exactly 2 rows. The mapping looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

As answered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268518/2442991) the problem is the use of **list** and **list-index**: in this case the ids of the children have to start from 0 and any missing index will cause Hibernate to generate a null value for it.

In my case the first child had id = 1, so a null row for 0 was being created.